# Bootstrap 3. Центрирование колонок внутри row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть стандартная бутстраповская верстка (в бутстрап 3 еще используются флоаты, а не флексбоксы):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что у меня может быть любое количество элементов с `.col-md-2` и мне нужно, чтобы если их в колонке меньше чем 6 то они центрировались в ряду. Какие есть способы сделать такое не перебивая кучу стилей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно ввести два дополнительных класса и потом использовать их вместе с `row` и `col-`.

```css
.row-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.col-center {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-center">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-center">col-md-2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-center">col-md-2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не будет корректно кстати работать, так как bootstrap перепишет `float: none` (попробуйте в Вашем коде подключить его) придётся `!important` использовать

Comment: @Dmitrii Sedov, посмотрите, пожалуйста, работает с подключенным Bootstrap 3.3.7 https://jsfiddle.net/8vdmpght/1/